# Oracle SQL: Get the last eight months of data (with YEAR and MONTH columns)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has columns YEAR and MONTH, which are varchars, which have a format like MONTH = '02', YEAR = '2011'.

What query can I use to get the last eight months of data, excluding the current month?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
where to_date(year || month, 'YYYYMM') 
       between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -8) and trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable 
WHERE (year, month) IN
(
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -level), 'RRRR') AS year, 
  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -level), 'MM') AS month
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 8
)
```

Another version:

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable 
WHERE year||month IN
(
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -level), 'RRRRMM') AS yearmonth
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 8
)
```

Comment: These aren't getting July.  They are returning June through December.

Comment: @Cybernate - I believe you want to eliminate the -1 in your `ADD_MONTHS` call and do <= 8 in your CONNECT BY.  That will return December 2010 through July 2011.

Comment: @Muhd Justin: My bad.. removed the -1

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of is this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MONTH || YEAR) IN ('012011','122010', et cetera)
```

It is a brute force method, so it is not feasible if you want your query to generalize.